# jQuery Vmap refresh with function load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I'm working with the following plugin: http://jqvmap.com/ with brought me a proper map of a country with its distinct regions.

I want to refresh the page with post data to filter some information when a click occurs. I used the load function which seems pretty easy to use but even if the function is reached, nothing happens afterwards.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#francemap').vectorMap({
        map: 'france_fr',
        hoverOpacity: 0.5,
        hoverColor: "#EC0000",
        backgroundColor: "#444444",
        color: "#FACC2E",
        borderColor: "#000000",
        selectedColor: "#EC0000",
        enableZoom: false,
        showTooltip: true,

        onRegionClick: function(element, code, region)
        {
            var url = "home";
            $(document).load(url, {region:region});
        }
    });
});
```

So if I basically clic on a region: nothing happens. Even thought the onRegionClick function is reached.

My bet is that it is a "DOM level issue" like i'm calling the document selector inside the $("#francemap") but I can't make sure and moreover I don't know how to overcome this.

Thank you for reading me

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh the page, u need

```
window.location = url+"#"+region;
```

```
$(document).load(function() {}) 
// Bind an event handler to the "load" JavaScript event.
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/kabh31ju/)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, it obviously works but the struggle is that I need a post action solution. Function load was perfect for it since a form is too heavy for that and a window.location implies a url modification.

Comment: why don't you use ajax to post the data

Comment: load is an Ajax method, isn't it? I don't get why it doesn't work